# bind dropdown and set selected value using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

I have a form which populates location data, using angularJS. The form has 3 dropdowns for Location Type, Time Zone and Parent. For an existing location, I want the attributes to be selected in the dropdowns when the data is loaded. However, in following implementation, the dropdowns are populated, but the values are not selected.

### HTML:

```
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:20%"><label for="locationType">{{'_LocationTypeLabel_' | i18n}}:</label></td>
                    <td style="width:25%"><select data-ng-model="vm.locationSettings.basicSettings.locationType.locationTypeId" data-ng-options="l.locationTypeDisplayName for l in vm.locationTypes track by l.locationTypeId" /></td>
                    <td style="width:20%"><label for="parent">{{'_LocationParentLabel_' | i18n}}:</label></td>
                    <td style="width:25%"><select data-ng-model="vm.locationSettings.basicSettings.parent" data-ng-options="l.locationName for l in vm.parentLocations track by l.locationId" /></td>  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:20%"><label for="timezone">{{'_TimeZonesLabel_' | i18n}}:</label></td>
                    <td style="width:25%"><select data-ng-model="vm.locationSettings.basicSettings.timeZone" data-ng-options="l.displayName for l in vm.timeZones track by l.timeZoneId" /></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
```

### controller:

```
function loadLocationData() {
        clientcontext.clientlookup.getAllPublic().then(function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                vm.locationTypes.push(data.results[i]);
            }
            clientcontext.location.getLocations(vm.clientId, 1)
              .then(function (data) {
                  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                      vm.parentLocations.push(data[i]);
                  }
                  systemcontext.systemlookup.getTimeZones()
                    .then(function (data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            vm.timeZones.push(data[i]);
                        }
                        //set the location attributes
                        vm.locationSettings.basicSettings = basicSettingsFactory.init().then(function () {
                            systemcontext.systemlookup.getTimeZoneById(vm.locationSettings.basicSettings.timeZone)
                           .then(function (data) {
                               vm.locationSettings.basicSettings.timeZone = data;
                           });
                        });
                    });
              });
        });
    }
```

the location attributes are populated using a separate factory, as - `vm.locationSettings.basicSettings = basicSettingsFactory.init()`

```
 function basicSettingsFactory($q, $http, $route, $location, $rootScope, $window, common, clientcontext, localize) {
    var basicLocationSettings = {};

    function getLocationDetails() {
        clientcontext.location.getLocationById($route.current.params.clientId, $route.current.params.id)
  .then(function (data) {
      basicLocationSettings.id = data.locationId;
      basicLocationSettings.parent = data.fkParentLocationId;
      basicLocationSettings.locationType = data.locationType;
      basicLocationSettings.locationName = data.locationName;
      basicLocationSettings.locationDisplayName = data.locationDisplayName;
      basicLocationSettings.locationCode = data.locationCode;
      basicLocationSettings.isActive = data.activeStatus;
      basicLocationSettings.timeZone = data.fkTimeZoneId;
  });
    }
    return {

        // Initializes the entire monitoring probe scope variables.
        init: function () {
            getLocationDetails();
            return basicLocationSettings;
        }

    };
}
})();
```

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong, that doesn't set the selected value in the dropdowns?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
Could the issue be that, the attribute locationtype has a integer value like 3, but what's bound to the dropdown is a LocationType object?

Comment: Set up a plunkr and post the link here.

Answer (score 0):

Look your updated code, it might help you.

```
 function basicSettingsFactory($q, $http, $route, $location, $rootScope, $window, common, clientcontext, localize) {
    var basicLocationSettings = {};
     // Need to put the default Ids for selection display.
     //The code look like this
     basicLocationSettings.id = default; //defaylt Id

    function getLocationDetails() {
    clientcontext.location.getLocationById($route.current.params.clientId, $route.current.params.id)
      .then(function (data) {
          basicLocationSettings.id = data.locationId;
          basicLocationSettings.locationName = data.locationName;
          basicLocationSettings.locationDisplayName = data.locationDisplayName;
          });
    }
    return {
        // Initializes the entire monitoring probe scope variables.
        init: function () {
            getLocationDetails();
            return basicLocationSettings;
        }

    };
}
})();
```

Comment: default == your default existing ids.

Comment: there are no such default values for these attributes. These attributes refer to another entity (e.g. LocationType, TimeZone, etc...), so until they are populated, I can't assign a value here.